# Verify / Ensure test code is only called in tests, not in production code

Tags: java, maven, testing, checkstyle, rule

In one of our projects at work, we have started using [Guava's VisibleForTesting](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) to annotate "helper" methods that must only be used for testing (e.g. a Setter to allow for service mocks to be "injected"). In production, the application should use Spring's Autowired to "get" its services.

Is there a way to check if code annotated with **VisibleForTesting** is only called in test code (static analysis, not if someone tries funny stuff via reflection)?

Comment: Seems like constructor injection is what you should be using to avoid this hack.

Comment: I agree. Guava has a lot of nice features; but if you want to make sure that something is not in the production code, then heck: don't put it there...

Comment: I basically agree, I'll have to recheck, why we don't use constructor injection

Answer (score 0):

For anyone suffering from the same fallacy (in this specific case of having Setters only for Testing):

1. Use Constructor Injection instead
2. If for some obscure reason, the production code cannot be modified, Mockito's [InjectMocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) (at least) keeps your production code clean

Rationale: You cannot prevent others **outside** of your project's build environment to use this "test-only" code, so any effort regarding static code analysis will just create the illusion of safety (for you) and makes it even more surprising if someone actually "misues" that code.